# Disabling cache on specific part of page from above comment

Tags: cache

I am facing a problem in part of page of an extension on comments
When cache is enabled, there is some json token error due to cache
When cache is disabled, the user can easily post in comment

Is there a way i can add up line of codes so that on body of page - when comments are loaded, cache is disabled , rest the whole page remains otherwise cached

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JotCache component](https://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension/core-enhancements/performance/jotcache/) for this problem solution.

Comment: am using jotcache, but how to disable part comment in it

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude your comments extension from caching (see [JotCache documentation](http://www.jotcomponents.net/home/web-programming/jotcache/jotcache-help/148-jotcache-ver-6-x-help)).

Comment: JSE is not a forum thread.  The site design is has been deliberately developed to prevent a long flowing page of chronologically listed interactions.  Please edit your earlier answer to include your message from this answer, then delete this second post.  Your two posts do not contradict each other, so you can safely merge your advice into a single post as an edit on the original.  Thank you in advance.